# Change the Legend shape in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, formatting

I got a request to change the shape of the legend in one of the report from rectangle to circle shape,

currently report looks like this

[image: screenshot]

but the required shape look like this

[image: screenshot]

I checked the properties of the legend but there is no way I found to change the shape or use image.

Any idea how can achieve that?

thanks

Comment: If you post an example of your SQL for the report dataset, I can show you how to use my answer.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Thanks @aduguid I am on leave at the moment I will check it when I am back to work.. appreciate your help

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this with a matrix. First you have to insert a rectangle in the cell you want to use for the legend. Then the assign the background color of the rectangle to the column in an expression e.g. `=Fields!ColorHex.Value`. Next insert the circle image over top of the rectangle.

You should be able to use the same dataset for the matrix (legend) as you do for the chart. You'll need to add a column for the [ColorHex](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) values to your dataset. Then you can also reference the same column in the chart for the colors.

#### Report Preview:

[image: screenshot]

#### Circle .png file with transparency:

I created the image using [GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program)](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

[image: Circle]

#### Example SQL for color hex codes

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( '#90EE90', 'Due next month')
, ( '#FAFAD2', 'Due this month')
, ( '#FFB6C1', 'Overdue')
) tbl ([ColorHex], [GroupType])
```

#### Example XML for the .rdl report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="YourDataSource">
      <DataSourceReference>YourDataSource</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>68eb8e17-19b1-4ab3-8315-91c1cb31c63a</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>YourDataSource</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( '#90EE90', 'Due next month')
, ( '#FAFAD2', 'Due this month')
, ( '#FFB6C1', 'Overdue')
) tbl ([ColorHex], [GroupType]) </CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="ColorHex">
          <DataField>ColorHex</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="GroupType">
          <DataField>GroupType</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix3">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>0.9125cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>3.21438cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.89146cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Rectangle Name="Rectangle3">
                          <ReportItems>
                            <Image Name="Image3">
                              <Source>Embedded</Source>
                              <Value>legend_template</Value>
                              <Sizing>FitProportional</Sizing>
                              <Height>0.89146cm</Height>
                              <Width>0.9125cm</Width>
                              <Style>
                                <Border>
                                  <Style>None</Style>
                                </Border>
                              </Style>
                            </Image>
                          </ReportItems>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <RightBorder>
                              <Color>White</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </RightBorder>
                            <BackgroundColor>=Fields!ColorHex.Value</BackgroundColor>
                          </Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="GroupType1">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!GroupType.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>GroupType1</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="GroupType">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression>=Fields!GroupType.Value</GroupExpression>
                    </GroupExpressions>
                  </Group>
                  <SortExpressions>
                    <SortExpression>
                      <Value>=Fields!GroupType.Value</Value>
                    </SortExpression>
                  </SortExpressions>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember />
                    <TablixMember />
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="RowGroup">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression />
                    </GroupExpressions>
                  </Group>
                  <TablixHeader>
                    <Size>0.07938cm</Size>
                    <CellContents>
                      <Textbox Name="Textbox9">
                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                        <Paragraphs>
                          <Paragraph>
                            <TextRuns>
                              <TextRun>
                                <Value />
                                <Style />
                              </TextRun>
                            </TextRuns>
                            <Style />
                          </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox9</rd:DefaultName>
                        <Style>
                          <Border>
                            <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                            <Style>None</Style>
                          </Border>
                          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                        </Style>
                      </Textbox>
                    </CellContents>
                  </TablixHeader>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
            <Height>0.89146cm</Height>
            <Width>4.20625cm</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>0.35097in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>1.656in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageHeight>21cm</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>29.7cm</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>0.75cm</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>0.75cm</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>0.75cm</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>0.75cm</BottomMargin>
        <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>2</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>4</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <EmbeddedImages>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="legend_template">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>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</ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
  </EmbeddedImages>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>6203a576-d7cc-4b57-9a9b-12cf325d6203</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```